# Java JDilaog - make it modal but non blocking

Tags: java, modal-dialog, blocking, jdialog

I'm trying to create a login system with a popup login box, and I want the user to be forced to enter their credentials (or click cancel) before they do anything else. Unfortunately, setting modal to True and then invoking the box with setVisible() will cause the dialog to block any underlying threads. This is unfavorable as their will likely be some sort of underlying data collection that should continue to run during the login process. Is there any way to make the login box modal & non-blocking without creating any other threads?

EDIT: As requested, here's some code in a demo application:

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            login.showLogin();
            if (login.isLoggedIn()) {
                loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            }

            if (!logoutButton.isEnabled()) {
                logoutButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

The showLogin() method is just a call to setVisible(). After the user enters his username and password, the mechanism checks to see if the user successfully logged in with the isLoggedIn() method. If the call was non-blocking, this code would run right through without waiting to authenticate the user first. I even checked it in the IntelliJ debugger and the if statement doesn't get executed until the user clicks login or cancel.

Comment: show us the relevant code

Comment: I have never heard of a modal dialog that was blocking threads... Some code samples are required.

Comment: @dotvav Sorry, just added some code.

Comment: OK. Either I misunderstood the question or it was edited. I thought you were meaning **all the threads** were halted.